# stack panel having different horizontal alignment

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Is it possible for a horizontally aligned stackpanel to have items which have different horizontal alignment ie. One is left aligned and one is right aligned? I tried multiple ways but i think Grid is the only option?

Regards,
Bhavik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - a `StackPanel` by definition pushes all of its items to one side or the other.  You could use a `Grid` or `DockPanel` (from the Silverlight tooolkit) instead.